# Чужая флешка. Как просканировать на предмет RMS/RAT?

Tags: безопасность

Попала на днях мне в руки флешка от малознакомого человека. У меня параноя по тому боюсь что ее заразили предварительно шпион программами. Как убедится в ее безопасности  или предварительно чем либо просканировать?

Comment: Отключите автозапуск флешки (гуглите как), а лучше не мудрите и поставьте антивирус

Comment: Я бы подключил ее к машине с Linux и посмотрел бы что там. Подозрительные файлы на virustotal отсылал и смотрел бы результаты.

Comment: Что Вы собираетесь с этой флешкой делать? Только просканировать? тогда не делайте ничего - так надёжнее. Или использовать? тогда отформатируйте. Или взять оттуда некие файлы и использовать их? Вот тогда сканируйте - и флешку вообще, и файлы на ней. Лучше всего загрузившись со свежего LiveCD, записанного из образа, загруженного с сайта какого-нибудь надёжного антивируса (Kaspersky или DrWeb подойдёт).

Comment: а если эта флэшка USB Rubber Ducky то никакой антивирус не поможет :)